# Console.log() Output in Debugger is Being Displayed Oddly

Tags: google-chrome

I think I might have changed a setting in Google Chrome debugger, but am unsure how to change it back. When I do `console.log($('.foo'));` I usually get a tree of the DOM structure. Instead, I am getting a bunch of stuff that appears to be the properties of the node (see screenshot). How would I change the output back to seeing a DOM tree?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13486942

According to jarodtaylor, you need to append `[0]` at the end of your statement (ie - `console.log($('p')[0]);`)

This apparently is a new 'feature' that Google has introduced in Chrome 24. Is there a way to disable this new feature?